# Converting HTML5+CSS+JS project to Polymer (as PWA)

Tags: polymer, progressive-web-apps, web-component

I created a web application with HTML5/CSS/JS and using JavaScript template literals. I am in the process of converting HTML5 pages to use custom web components (rewriting the HTML pages) and make it PWA. 
However,

1. Application is not a single page application
2. Application uses responsive Material template (css and js that should stay)
3. I need to convert to Progressive Web App (PWA) using workbox.

I am looking for advise, if  Polymer or Lit-Element or HTMLElement would allow  maximum code reuse.

Also, any web application (HTML5 with css, js) can be converted to PWA - right?
Having web components will provide better performance, but not a criteria for converting to PWA?

Comment: I think Polymer is not developed any more

Comment: Start with [native Custom Elements](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements) If you start with Lit or Svelte or Hybrids you are learning the tool, not the underlying native technology

Comment: Note the Polymer Library and Polymer Elements are no longer maintained but Polymer in general is still developing LitElement and the PWA starter kit.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Polymer; I suggest you look into [lit-element](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/) for components and [lit-html](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/) for templates; they work very well together but you can use anything for templates, of course.

As far as I'm aware this is the official recommendation of people who were working on the Polymer project at Google. There is an active community on Slack you can go to for help, too.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, I have been looking into lit-element and that seems like a great fit. I don't need to build a single page app to convert to PWA later.. right? Polymer-cli seems to be supporting single page app. Wasn't sure what that meant.

Comment: `Polymer-cli` is just a command line tool, don't bother with it. Yes you can create both single page apps and PWAs with custom elements, either native or libraries like lit-element.